# Script bundles not specifying type

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I use script bundles in several of my web-sites. This works fine except in Internet Explorer 8.

I think, thow I'm not sure, that this would be solved by adding type="text/javascript" to the script tag. Is this possible using script bundles?

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: @ekenman Please give us specific examples of what is happening and what you have already tried. Code is always welcomed!

Comment: @chrstiandev OK....2.0.3, totally missed this one.

Comment: I did add an answer too, in case that wasn't the issue...did you install this via `NuGet` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IE 8` will not support **JQuery 2.x**, so check which version you're bundling up.  Bundling works on IE 8, so I suspect the issue is with the JQuery files.

[`JQuery Browser Support`](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Few other things to check:

1. IIS version, since IIS 6 does have some issues with Bundling
2. Check, using something like IE Tools(F12), Chrome tools or Firebug to make sure the resources are being loaded up.

**EDIT**: Based on comment, re: unsupported JQuery.

If you're using NuGet,

- Go to references, Manage NuGet packages
- Uninstall Jquery
- Go to [`NuGet website`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/), and select package version.
- and run this **Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.10.2** in [`Package Manager Console`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console)

Answer (score 1):

I think because IE8 not support HTML5. In later browser it's not need to use type="text/javascript"